# JS+PHP Form Validation issue

Tags: javascript, php, forms

My problem is, I want my ***form*** to be **validated in js *before* php sends it to my email**. Thats not happening. The form is being sent even with blank fields.

- it is not a problem with the script which validates the form. The validation - the js code itself - works fine.

The problem is, that the *validation* is kind of **secondary** to the php `action` in the ***form*** tag.

In other words: `action="contact-engine.php"` is previous to the `onsubmit="return validateForm()"`.

Now if I delete the `action="contact-engine.php"` from my form tag, the js code will work just fine, but thats not how i want it...

So here is HTML:

```
<form name="myForm" method="POST" onsubmit="return validateForm(myForm)" action="contact-engine.php">
    <label for="Name" id="name">1. Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name">
    <label for="Email" id="email">2. E-mail:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email">
    <label for="Message" id="messg">3. Message:</label>
    <textarea name="Message" rows="20" cols="20" id="Message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" class="submit-button">
```

JS:

```
function validateForm(myForm) {
var x = document.forms["myForm"]["Name"].value;
var y = document.forms["myForm"]["Email"].value;
var z = document.forms["myForm"]["Message"].value;

if ((x == null || x == "")&&(y == null || y == "")&&(z == null || z == "")) {
    document.getElementById("name").style.color = "#ff0000";
    document.getElementById("email").style.color = "#ff0000";
    document.getElementById("messg").style.color = "#ff0000";
    return false;
}else if ((y == null || y == "")) {
    document.getElementById("email").style.color = "#ff0000";
    document.getElementById("name").style.color = "#111111";
    document.getElementById("messg").style.color = "#111111";
    return false;
}else if ((z == null || z == "")) {
    document.getElementById("messg").style.color = "#ff0000";
    document.getElementById("email").style.color = "#111111";
    document.getElementById("name").style.color = "#111111";        
    return false;
}else {
  return true;
}
```

And PHP:

```
    <?php

$EmailFrom = "whatever@o2.pl";  
$EmailTo = "wherever@yahoo.com";
$Subject = "Message from";
$Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name'])); 
$Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email'])); 
$Message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Message'])); 

// validation
$validationOK=true;
if (!$validationOK) {
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
  exit;
}

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $Name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $Email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $Message;
$Body .= "\n";

// send email 
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");

// redirect to success page 
if ($success){
print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=../thanks.php\">";
}
//else{
  //print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
//}
?>
```

So as you can surely see I'm missing the connection between PHP and JS somewhere, but I'm clueless where and how and whatever.

While submitting the form it simply runs the PHP and displays success site.

So how do I prevent this from happening?

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Use HTML5 `required` attribute for form elements.

Comment: Yes i know this attribute, but I'm aiming in some elegant solution :) I want  js to change label colors and required seems to prevent that from hapening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `this` into the `validateForm` function.
Here is a short example of validating that the input is not `test`.

index.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="validate.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="http://google.com" onsubmit="return handleSubmit(this);">
      <input id="q" name="q" type="text" />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

validate.js:

```
function handleSubmit(form) {
  var q = form.querySelector("#q");
  return q.value !== "test";
}
```

Comment: I'm probably not making myself clear - it is not a problem for me to write script that validates the form. The validation - the js code itself - works fine. The problem is, that the validation is kind of secondary to the **php** `action`. In other words: `action="contact-engine.php"` is previous to the `onsubmit="return validateForm()"`. I can delete the `action="contact-engine.php"` from my **form** tag, thus making the js code work, but thats not the case...

Comment: Have you tried my example? It does not execute the action if my validation fails. I really think it is because you are not passing `this`. `this` becomes the element on which the submit action occurs; hence the form in this case. Your code is passing in `myForm`, which is not know, it is `undefined`. I bet this makes your function always fail.

Comment: Yes! It's ALIVE! ;)  Thanks so much, that was clearly the case. I did try your hint before, but probably made some mistake, today I've checked anagin, and It runs like a rocket :) Well done, and thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

[Data form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation) would be a better way to approach this. Notice the [`required` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation#The_required_attribute), which will prevent the form from being submitted if the fields have not been populated.

```html
<form name="myForm" method="POST" action="contact-engine.php">
    <label for="Name" id="name">1. Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" required>
    <label for="Email" id="email">2. E-mail:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" required>
    <label for="Message" id="messg">3. Message:</label>
    <textarea name="Message" rows="20" cols="20" id="Message" required></textarea>
  
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" class="submit-button">
</form>
```

Comment: Yes i know this attribute, but I'm aiming in some elegant solution :) I want  js to change label colors and required seems to prevent that from hapening

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="myForm" method="POST" action="contact-engine.php">
    <label for="Name" id="name">1. Name:</label>
    <input type="text" onblur="validateForm()" name="Name" id="Name" required>
    <label for="Email" id="email">2. E-mail:</label>
    <input type="text" onblur="validateForm()" name="Email" id="Email" required>
    <label for="Message" id="messg">3. Message:</label>
    <textarea name="Message" onblur="validateForm()" rows="20" cols="20" id="Message" required></textarea>

    <input type="submit" disabled="true" id="subm" name="submit" value="Send" class="submit-button">
</form>
<script>
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.getElementById("Name").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("Email").value;
    var z = document.getElementById("Message").value;
    var passed = true;
    if ((x == null || x == "") { document.getElementById("name").style.color = "#ff0000"; passed = false; } else { document.getElementById("name").style.color = "#111111"; }
    if ((y == null || y == "")) { document.getElementById("email").style.color = "#ff0000"; passed = false; } else { document.getElementById("email").style.color = "#111111"; }
    if ((z == null || z == "")) { document.getElementById("messg").style.color = "#ff0000"; passed = false; } else { document.getElementById("messg").style.color = "#111111"; }
    if (passed) {
        document.getElementById("subm").disabled = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("subm").disabled = true;
    }
}       

</script>
```

Comment: This still doesn't solve my problem, because the problem is that the 'action' attribute surpass the 'onsubmit' 'onClick' ones. In other words - php doesn't wait for js to validate the form. I'm missing some way of connecting these two..

Comment: Try disabling the button, i have changed my example to show how you can enable the button on validation

Comment: Did that, not working, besides, not elegant enought, with all due respect :) My teacher always told me we shouldn't mix HTML with JS by `onblur`, `onfocus` ect. Not sure why but I trust him ;) Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I am not saying don't use `JS`, for error styling, you can validate your inputs by `CSS`.
Checkout this example for validating required fields.

```css
input:invalid,
textarea:invalid {
  border-color: red !important;
}
form {
  padding: 20px; 
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
form div {
  padding: 5px;
}
label {
  display: block;
}
input + label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
input[type=text],
input[type=email],
textarea {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form>
      <div>
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
      </div>
      
      <div>
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required />
      </div>
    
      <div>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-1" value="choice-1" required />
        <label for="radio-choice-1">Choice 1</label>
        
        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-2" value="choice-2" required />
        <label for="radio-choice-2">Choice 2</label>
      </div>
        
      <div>
        <label for="textarea">Comment</label>
        <textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="textarea" id="textarea" required></textarea>
      </div>
    
      <div class="buttons">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </div>
    </form>
```